# How to get the value of adjacent columns after a nested match in excel

Tags: excel

I have something like this:

[image]

I need some formula which get the value of cell C10="informatics" coming from the condition that the results is 70 and the student is Lucy.
I tried several ways...until now i reach that point:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(C:C;MATCH("70",B:B,0))"None")
```

But of course it gaves me Carl results on math.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, just needed concatenate data:

[image]

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11;MATCH(C18&D18;$A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11;0))
```

or directly

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11;MATCH("lucy70";$A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11;0))
```

Depending on your Excel version, you may need to enter the formula as an array formula, so introduce it pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>

Comment: It worked perfectly inside the IFERROR, otherwise it gave me #N/A!

Comment: @Gipsy If it returns N/A it means there is no match. Consider if maybe there is extra blanks somewhere or something else because, as example,  for matching `lucy` and `lucy ` are 2 different values